Edit Collections Variables in Power Apps Template
I started a new Power App from "Help Desk" template to have a look, but I didn't find a way to edit the data in these tables or where they are stored,

I have checked the variable doc and the collection tables are supposed to be modified easily.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/working-with-variables#types-of-variables
It is finding a way to modify these tables.


Go to Apps and select OnStart event to view collection data, here you can change values.
